# SQL Query crafting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Edited outputs: no file names or trailing slashes are included**

I have a database with potentially thousands thousands of records (we're talking a 2MB result string if it was just `SELECT * FROM xxx` in a standard use case.

Now for reasons of security this result cannot be held anywhere for much more processing.

There is a path field where I want to extract all records with each level of folder structure.

So run the query one way I get every record in the root:

```
C:\
```

Query again another way I get every record in the first folder level:

```
C:\a\
C:\b\
```

etc

Then of course I will GROUP somehow in order to return

```
C:\a\
C:\b\
```

and not

```
C:\a\
C:\a\
C:\b\
C:\b\
```

hopefully you get the idea?
Any answers that at least move me in the right direction I will be grateful for. I really am stumped where to start with this as downloading every record and processing is far from the ideal solution in my context. (Which is what we do now).

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
C:\a\b\c\d
C:\a\b\c
C:\
C:\a\b
C:\g
D:\x
D:\x\y
```

**Sample output 1**

```
C:\
D:\
```

**Sample output 2**

```
C:\a
C:\g
D:\x
```

**sample output 3**

```
C:\a\b
D:\x\y
```

**sample output 4**

```
C:\a\b\c
```

**sample output 5**

```
C:\a\b\c\d
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I can't figure out what you want/mean. Please provide sample data and sample query output. And how many directory levels down are you going to go?

Comment: 2MB is just a million widechar characters which is not much at all. If you have trouble processing this in the database, you could process it in any program code (do you know any programming languages?). You don't have to store it anywhere on disk, just process it in memory and you'll be pretty safe.

Comment: I agree with Martin this solution is very dependent on RDBMS.

Comment: @Bohemian added. Could be infinite directory levels in reality

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree but this is a webapp on a mobile phone. I can process it on the server but once it's expanded out into the html we're talking a massive amount of html to send to the browser (it crashes the browser). So sending in bits as required from the database is much more efficient in my mind.

Comment: How sending from the db to a mobile is related to saving the data into a folder structure in disk?

Comment: You usually don't send data from a database directly to a mobile device. I assume there's a server application, possibly ASP or PHP that can do the processing?

Comment: @GolezTrol of course there is (both ASP and PHP actually!) but I am trying to refrain from having to process every single record every time I want to go one directory deeper (besides doing a `LIKE C:\a\%` to narrow it down). I dont see any logic in iterating through say 3000 records in PHP to spew out maybe 2 folders when a query may just give me 2 results in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do if you have only folders: `SELECT DISTINCT path FROM table WHERE LENGTH(path) - LENGTH(replace(path,'\','')) = N`

If you have only file names then it depends on whether you have an `INSTR` function (or some regexp substitution function) provided by the RDBMS. In all cases, depends on the string functions that are available.

Comment: Looks promising at first, but doesn't take into account some cases. In particular, the OP's example doesn't contain the `C:\a` path proper, only it's sub-, subsub- etc. folders. And yet the result set is expected to contain `C:\a` when the corresponding level is requested, as per the question.

Comment: Agreed I suppose and actually It's getting the first/second level that is the most important since as you get deeper using a `LIKE C:\a\b%` to narrow it down - whether or not this is relevant.